# $f: M' \otimes N \rightarrow M \otimes N$ that is not injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ - commutative ring

$M' \subset M$, $N$ - $R$ - modules

How can i build an example for map $f: M' \otimes N \rightarrow M \otimes N$ that is not injective and $f(a \otimes b) = a \otimes b \in M \otimes N$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb Q$ and $N = \Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ as $\Bbb Z$-modules (i.e abelian groups).